# Title in Google Search Result differs from settings in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, seo, google-search, yoast

My website titles are set with a seperator in Wordpress (websites with both Yoast & RankMath plugin).
In my setting I'm using a seperator like below:

- **My sentence is here | Company name**

But in google it's displayed as

- **Company name: My sentence is here**

My description is the same tho. I guess there is an overruling somewhere that pushes the title with ':' in it. Does someone know how to fix it?

-> Some pages do index right, some don't.

Comment: Can you provide us you website url ? Did you tried to read your <title> tag content with and without plugins ?

Comment: For example: webstek.be

Comment: Your title is good. Did you tried to ask Google to re-crawl your website ?

Comment: Yes, done it multiple times within a year. I don't know where the errors are made...